Help setting up trust for self signed certificate for SMIME
I created my own Certificate Authority, using this guide:
https://docs.openssl.org/3.0/man1/CA.pl/#examples
I then created several email certificates for my email addresses.
I imported my root CA into Ubuntu's certificate store, via
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates

The Root CA shows up in the dialog and in the Passwords and Keys app.
I imported the email certificates into Evolution, but when I attempt to send myself a signed and encrypted email, I get the following error:

Detailed error: Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not
trusted by the user. (-8172) - Cannot add SMIMEEncKeyPrefs attribute

How do I get Evolution to trust the subordinate email certificates?

Setting the attributes of the authority's certificate in Evolution does not have the desired effect. This helped in my case:
Error when sending signed mail in Evolution

Thanks! I ended up finding a different solution.

Evolution has it's own CA trust, separate from the system.
In Evolution, I had to import the ROOT CA certificate, as well as the intermediate certificate into the trust store, then it would work.
Alternatively, in another iteration, I imported only the root certificate and added the intermediate CA to the user certificate and imported that chain as my personal certificate, and it worked and was trusted.
Order does matter on this, so from a little script I made where $FILE is user input name (e.g. user.domain.tld):
cat intermediate/certs/$FILE.cert.pem intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem> intermediate/certs/$FILE.combined.cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in intermediate/certs/$FILE.combined.cert.pem -inkey intermediate/private/$FILE.key.pem -out intermediate/private/$FILE.combined.p12

